# Migrating Cortex Application from Development Board to microcontroller chip

Tags: stm32, cortex-m3, cortex-m, nucleo

I have been working on different micro-controllers and I am new to Arm cortex architecture.

I have developed an application on NUCLEO-F207ZG (powered by STM32F207ZG).

The application is supposed to run on stm32f207vc.

Currently, I have made separate projects in STM32 Workbench, one for development board and other for the stand-alone microcontroller.

This seems to be an ugly approach to me as it involves a lot of hassle in copying files from one project to another and then working around to successfully build the project, and I am sure I am not aware of certain good approaches.

Is it possible to run the same project for both microcontrollers? (I think there should be a solution as both are from similar series, with different memory capacities and pin count). One thing that I see is that I may have to make a change in linker script, changing the amount of RAM and ROM that the target device houses.

Looking forward to methods to be able to develop applications faster.

Below is the link to the datasheet. Both devices are listed in the same datasheet for being similar.

https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/389/stm32f205rb-956262.pdf

Thanks and advance

Comment: Please list all of the important differences between the ZG and VC parts. Or, provide links to the datasheets for these devices.

Comment: What about using conditionals at compile time?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have added datasheet of the device. Thanks

Comment: @ScottSeidman  conditional compilation in the linker script section and startup files? Sorry for asking too many questions, the architecture is completely new to me. Thanks for response anyway

Comment: In the code:  https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_078.HTM. you would still need to specify the processor the the compiler, but you use conditionals to include the right libtary files and such.

Comment: @ScottSeidman  I get your point now. Thank you for sharing the link, I have good understanding of conditional compilation though. I thought you are mentioning conditional compilation to select the processor parameters somewhere. Yes conditional compilation would be needed to select proper libraries, but in my case that won't be needed. The code would run as such for them being a member of same family. Thank you for pointing it out anyway :)

Comment: Much of the issue here may be being victimized by whatever IDE you are using, rather than having a good software development practice built around version control and build automation that can build from the same sources to distinct output directories for different configurations. Way back when, MCU vendors could make up unsustainable practices. But the reality that it is still software work is now well apparent - you need to be able to use the same source practices as all the other code in an organization. An IDE can be a convenience if you can make it cooperate, otherwise it is a hinderance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This applies to Eclipse CDT + GNU MCU Eclipse plugin, and *might* work in other eclipse based IDEs like yours.

In the Project - Properties - C/C++ Build - Settings dialog there is a dropdown list at the top to select configurations, configured by default to switch between debug and release build. It's possible to define additional configurations there, e.g. a debug/release pair for the other MCU. Then you can adjust the linker settings to use another linker script file, define different macros in the compiler preprocessor settings for conditional compilation, have different include paths, etc.

Comment: Thank you for detailed description. I will check that ASAP. I am using system workbench which is powered by Eclipse itself. This might be the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A very quick scan of the datasheet suggests that the VC part is a strict subset of the ZG part. The VC part has fewer pins so you can't use ports F or G, and it has less flash memory.

If my interpretation is correct, and you should definitely spend some time to verify, then any code that runs on the VC should also run on the ZG. I suggest that you try writing all of your code with the VC version as the target. If I'm right then this code will run directly on the ZG part. At worst you might need to tell the tools to assume a different target processor and recompile.

Comment: Thank you for your response Elliot.

Comment: The Approach seems perfect. I've written application code considering VC. Code written for board(ZG) works on VC. I'm creating a separate project for creation of startup files and linker scrip accordingly, copying files from one project (ZG) to another (VC). I am debugging (print messages) on ZG board and commenting those debug statements in VC part (its a headache). The basic plan is to use conditional compilation for printing and getting rid of copying files. 
The only worry is if the code would behave same in real world by using same project for both. Guess hit and try is way to go. Thanks

Comment: Often leveraging the subsetting will work, but there are places in the STM32 family where you occasionally find things such as the same GPIO pin being connected to say UART2 on a high end variant, but UART1 on a lower end one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It made me curious, can you name an example?

Comment: @chrisStratton thanks for bringing that up. I will definitely keep that in mind for future developments. Kindly share some references as well if possible.

Comment: There are definitely such difference between pin-compatible members of the STM32F03x and STM32F05x, I seem to recall there being such within the STM32F05x which only has a single UART in low end members, but am not currently seeing evidence of that in the data sheet; to believe the data sheet there's no UART on PA15 in the low end, it may be the available UART is actually mapped there (that's also a part that typically has twice as much flash as it claims to)